# Is there any case when a Stack or a Queue implementation with ArrayList gives better, faster performance then a LinkedList implemented in Java?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, stack, queue

In this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111334/queue-performance-wise-which-is-better-implementation-array-or-linked-list) I read the following:

> If you're doing comparatively few operations, ie less than 1000 or so enqueue/dequeues in total, then an array would be faster because it is contiguous in memory.

My question is: How caching an ArrayList works in Java? Are there cases, when an ArrayList implemented Queue or Stack perform better then a LinkedList implemented in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hen an ArrayList implemented Queue or Stack perform better then a LinkedList implemented in Java?

When the queue is almost always empty or with 1 element, ArrayList is faster and creates less garbage (ie none)

If you have a fast consumer, it will almost always consumer what ever the producer produces as it produces it.  This means there is typically 0 or 1 elements in the queue.  Under these conditions ArrayList is faster as it doesn't create any objects or produce garbage.

BTW ArrayDeque is a better choice because this performs well even if there is more than 1 element.

> How caching an ArrayList works in Java?

There is nothing special about the way the CPU caches accesses to an ArrayList.

Comment: If a Queue or a Stack is almost empty or with 1 element, we can call that an Arraylist,or basically whatever we want because, we will just add and remove with an Array, the order of that is irrelevant. Am I right, or missing something?

Comment: @codeme it's more the point that ArrayList is slow except when adding/removing the last element, in which case it is faster than Linkedlist.